# Understanding Scrapy Python: Refactoring parse method does not work

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I have a spider code that works.

```py
class MySpider(BaseScrapper):
    name = "my_spider"

    def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
        self.logger.info(f"Parse: Processing {response.url}")

        yield ScrapyItem(
            source=response.meta["source"],
            url=response.url,
            html=response.text,
        )

        links = self.extract_links(response)

        self.logger.info(f"Extracted {len(links)} links from {response.url}")

        for link in links:
            self.logger.info(f"Following link: {link.url}")
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=link.url,
                callback=self.parse,
                meta={
                    "source": response.meta["source"],
                },
            )
```

I tried refactoring the above code using 2 methods, something like the below and it does not work.

```py
    def follow_links(self, response, links):
        self.logger.info(f"Following {len(links)} links from {response.url}")
        for link in links:
            self.logger.info(f"Following link: {link.url}")
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=link,
                callback=self.parse,
                meta={
                    "source": response.meta["source"],
                },
            )

    def extract_and_follow_links(self, response):
        links = self.extract_links(response)
        self.logger.info(f"Extracted {len(links)} links from {response.url}")

        # TODO: Save the links to the database
        self.follow_links(response, links)

    def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
        self.logger.info(f"Parse: Processing {response.url}")

        yield ScrapyItem(
            source=response.meta["source"],
            url=response.url,
            html=response.text,
        )
    
       self.extract_and_follow_links(response)
```

A little background: *the start urls supplied by the BaseScrapper have been scrapped and the item pipelines picks it and raises DropItem exception. This is expected and I am more interested in new links on those pages.*

After I run the refactored code, it raises DropItem for the start urls and stops.

My question to you is - Why does the code behave differently when refactored.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your refactored code never yields the subsequent requests from the parse method...

You can interpret your code as a timeline of events in this way:

- a start url response is sent to the parse method
- the parse method calls the method `extract_and_follow_links`
- the `extract_and_follow_links` method then extracts links
- the `extract_and_follow_links` method then calls the `follow_links` method
- the `follow_links` method is a generator that iterates through the each of the links, creates a scrapy request object from the link and then yields the request back to the `extract_and_follow_links` method
- because the `extract_and_follow_links` never iterates over the `follow_links` generator, or saves a reference or returns the generator, this is where the timeline ends.

What you are trying to achieve would require at some point iterating over the yielded requests from the `follow_links` method and eventually yielding those requests from the `parse` method so that they can be dispatched to the scrapy engine and placed in the request queue to be processed.

For example:

```
    def follow_links(self, response, links):
        self.logger.info(f"Following {len(links)} links from {response.url}")
        for link in links:
            self.logger.info(f"Following link: {link.url}")
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=link,
                callback=self.parse,
                meta={
                    "source": response.meta["source"],
                },
            )

    def extract_and_follow_links(self, response):
        links = self.extract_links(response)
        self.logger.info(f"Extracted {len(links)} links from {response.url}")

        # TODO: Save the links to the database
        ########## return the iterator #########
        return self.follow_links(response, links) 


    def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
        self.logger.info(f"Parse: Processing {response.url}")

        yield ScrapyItem(
            source=response.meta["source"],
            url=response.url,
            html=response.text,
        )
    
       ########## yield requests from the iterator ############
       for request in self.extract_and_follow_links(response):
           yield request
```